# Protection against command injection with modsecurity

Tags: waf

I want to know if modsecurity can protect against command injection and file inclusion.
I tested modsecurity with free version and run dvwa which is vulnerable page .
But command injection is possible even if modsecurity rules are included in apache.conf.
Please answer me.

Answer (score 2):

Check inside file: `modsecurity_crs_40_generic_attacks.conf` and if your WAF is properly configured than it should react when you try to trigger command injection.

```
#
# OS Command Injection Attacks
#
# -=[ Rule Logic ]=-
# These rules look for attempts to access OS commands such as curl, wget and cc
# These commands are often used in injection attacks to force the victim web
# application to initiate a connection out to a hacker site to download, compile
# and install malicious toolkits such as those to participate in Botnets.
#
# -=[ References ]=- 
# http://projects.webappsec.org/OS-Commanding
# http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project
#
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(?i:(?:[\;\|\`]\W*?\bcc|\b(wget|curl))\b|\/cc(?:[\'\"\|\;\`\-\s]|$))" \
        "phase:2,rev:'2',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.8',maturity:'9',accuracy:'8',capture,t:none,t:normalisePath,ctl:auditLogParts=+E,block,msg:'System Command Injection',id:'950907',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-31',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1',tag:'PCI/6.5.2',logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0},skipAfter:END_COMMAND_INJECTION1"

SecMarker END_COMMAND_INJECTION1


#
# Command injection
#
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(?:\b(?:(?:n(?:et(?:\b\W+?\blocalgroup|\.exe)|(?:map|c)\.exe)|t(?:racer(?:oute|t)|elnet\.exe|clsh8?|ftp)|(?:w(?:guest|sh)|rcmd|ftp)\.exe|echo\b\W*?\by+)\b|c(?:md(?:(?:\.exe|32)\b|\b\W*?\/c)|d(?:\b\W*?[\\/]|\W*?\.\.)|hmod.{0,40}?\+.{0,3}x))|[\;\|\`]\W*?\b(?:(?:c(?:h(?:grp|mod|own|sh)|md|pp)|p(?:asswd|ython|erl|ing|s)|n(?:asm|map|c)|f(?:inger|tp)|(?:kil|mai)l|(?:xte)?rm|ls(?:of)?|telnet|uname|echo|id)\b|g(?:\+\+|cc\b)))" \
    "phase:2,rev:'3',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.8',maturity:'9',accuracy:'9',capture,t:none,t:cmdLine,ctl:auditLogParts=+E,block,msg:'System Command Injection',id:'950006',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-31',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1',tag:'PCI/6.5.2',logdata:'Matched Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}: %{MATCHED_VAR}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/COMMAND_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"

SecMarker END_COMMAND_INJECTION
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can. You can create custom rules and tailor them to the specific applications. Otherwise you risk blocking legitimate requests.

Here are some links that might be useful:

https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/issues/318

https://www.htbridge.com/blog/patching-complex-web-vulnerabilities-using-modsecurity-waf.html